# Can everything be above avarage?

Tags: probability

I think I heard a radio program say that everything can be above average and am wondering if I misheard or this can be the case. I Know that average has a lot of meanings e.g. range, median, mean, mode etc. and the only way I can think of it been the case if if the mode is used with e.g. two observations at the lowest value and only one observation at all the higher values. Is there another way that everything can be above average?

Comment: "Well, that's the news from Lake Wobegon, where all the women are strong, all the men are good looking, and all the children are above average."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the case of median, the answer is a definite no - the median takes the middle value (unless all the values are the same).

You're correct that it's possible for everything to be above or equal to the mode (e.g. {1,1,2,3})

For the mean, the only way this could occur would be if all the values were identical. However it is possible for all but one of the values to be above the mean, for example if there is one extremal value.

The range isn't really an average, but a measure of the spread of the data.

Comment: As an example, nearly everybody has an above average number of arms!